# The limit of a solution of the logistic equation as time tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

$$ \frac{dP}{dt} = 3P(4 - P),\quad P(0) = 2.$$

What value does $P$ approach as $t$ gets large, ie. as $t \to\infty$.

How do I solve this?
Is the idea to this question to first rearrange the equation so that there is a constant on the Right Hand Side, then you can integrate both sides with respect to $dt$?

Thanks

Comment: I think one should learn the easy way to find $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} P$ without actually solving the differential equation.  Thus my posted answer does not separate and integrate.  One should also learn how to separate and integrate, but it would be wrong to think that's the simplest way to answer the question posed here. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{dP}{dt} = 3P(4 - P),\quad P(0) = 2.
$$

Two posted answers so far have answered this by solving the differential equation.

If there is any reason for anyone to learn about differential equations, they should learn how to answer this question without solving this equation.

Notice that $P$ is intially between $2$ and $4$.  That means $P(4-P)$ is positive.  That means $P$ is increasing.  As long as $P$ is between $2$ and $4$, then $P$ is increasing.  But notice that if $P$ is more than $4$, then $P$ is decreasing.  And when $P$ is exactly $4$, then $dP/dt$ is zero, so $P$ is constant.

So:

- If $P$ is less than $4$ (but more than $0$) then $P$ gets bigger;
- If $P$ is more than $4$ then $P$ gets smaller;
- If $P$ should reach exactly $4$ then $P$ remains constant.

That tells you what $P$ approaches as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: If you read my post carefully, then you should see I started out with the "quick and dirty way", which is the same as yours. But yours is inaccurate. You cannot say "When $P$ is more than $4$" because $P$ never actually reaches $4$! And $P$ is always increasing.

Comment: @Deepak : Would you feel better if I had said _if_ $P$ is ever more than $4$?  It was a hypothetical to be used in a context in which one has not actually fully solved the equation.

Comment: . . . . ok, I've changed it to "if". ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

The rigorous way to solve this would be to solve the differential equation, get an expression for $P(t)$ and then take the limit $\lim_{t \to \infty}P(t)$.

But if you start out by assuming the limit exists, then at the limit, $\frac{dP}{dt}=0$ (i.e. loosely speaking, "P stops changing").

So solve $3P(4-P) = 0$ giving $P=4$ as the limiting value (ignore the other root $P=0$ because $P(0) = 2$ and $P$ is always increasing).

Note that what I did is a "quick and dirty" solution. If you're asked this in homework, a test or an examination, you should start by solving the differential equation. It's a separable first order differential equation.

You start by separating the variables:

$$\frac{dP}{3P(4-P)} = dt$$

Then integrate both sides. I find it easier to set the initial conditions as the lower bound of a definite integral.

$$\int_2^{P(t)}\frac{dP}{3P(4-P)} = \int_0^t 1dt$$

The integrand on the left hand side can be resolved quickly with partial fractions, and the rest is algebra.

Comment: Definitely the hard way!!

Comment: @MichaelHardy I started out by giving what I consider the "easy way" before going on to the rigorous "hard way". Is there an even easier way than my "easy way"?

Comment: You show that if $P$ reaches $4$ then $P$ remains constant, but you are less than explicit in saying what happens when $P\ne 4$.  At any rate I disagree with the proposition that the ONLY rigorous way to do this is to solve the equation.  Certainly you would solve the equation if you want to know how fast $P$ approaches $4$, but the argument that stops short of solving the equation can be stated rigorously.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I pointed out a major semantic error in your own answer above. And the only rigorous way to prove that convergence does, in fact, happen as expected is to solve the equation and take the limit.

Comment: I've changed "when" to "if" in my answer, so I hope you'll be happier with that.

Comment: It's better, but it's still not rigorous. Like I said, if this was a multiple choice question, then the quick method suffices. But if it's a "long answer" sort of question, some rigour is expected, and solving the differential equation becomes necessary.

Comment: Certainly it can be made rigorous by dotting some "i"s and crossing some "t"s, but answers here often leave some work to the student.  If you want rigor, how about the lack of any explicit proof in your answer of the fact that $P(4-P)$ remains nonzero for all values of $t$, so that dividing by it is permissible? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Leaving work to the student is fine, but misleading them that a particular answer is completely fine when most would regard it as a "shortcut" is not. It leaves them with the wrong idea. As for the latter part, the behaviour of $P$ becomes self-evident after solving the differential equation (a quick look at the bounds of integration should be convincing enough, anyway, since the lower bound is $2$). At any rate, I think you're quibbling for the sake of it, I don't want to take up any more space here, and I'll end with this.

Comment: It's not a "shortcut".  It shows that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}P=4$.  I does not show exactly how $P$ varies as $t$ changes, but that is not what was asked for.  It is fine as a way of showing that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}P=4$. That a student would not learn how to do this when confronted with this problem is what is not "fine".

Comment: I am not quibbling for the sake of quibbling.  What I wrote is a perfectly valid way of answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange first, as you say.

$$
\frac{dP}{P(4-P)} = 3\, dt\\
\because \frac1{P(4-P)} = \frac1{4}\left( \frac1{P} + \frac1{4-P} \right)\\
\therefore 3\int_0^t dt = \int_{P(0)}^{P(t)} \frac{dP}{P(4-P)} = \frac1{4}\int_{2}^{P} \left( \frac1{P} + \frac1{4-P} \right) dP \\
3t = \frac1{4}\left( \ln \left(\frac{P}{2}\right) - \ln \left(\frac{4-P}{2}\right)\right) = \frac1{4}\ln\frac{P}{4-P} \\
12t = \ln \frac{P}{4-P} \\
$$
Then rearrange this and we get
$$
P = \frac{4}{1+e^{-12t}}
$$

Now as $t\to \infty, e^{-t} \to 0$, so what can you say about P?

Comment: Definitely the hard way!!